# PHP: Do I need nested foreach loops or multiple arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm not sure of the terminology to describe what I need to do. Two nested foreach loops? Multiple arrays? A multi-dimensional array?

I am counting the total number of occurrences of each state (AK, AL, AR, etc)

```
$states_count[] = $state;
$count_by_state = array_count_values($states_count);
```

And `var_dump($count_by_state)` gives me

```
["AK"]=> int(3) ["AL"]=> int(6) ["AR"]=> int(4) ["AZ"]=> int(9) ["CA"]=> int(98) ["CO"]=> int(44) ....
```

So the Alaska total is 3, the Alabama total is 6, etc.

In separate code, I use this foreach to build a menu:

```
<?php $states = array('AK'=>'Alaska', 'AL'=>'Alabama'....  );

foreach ($states as $key => $value) {
echo $key; echo $value; echo ',';
}
```

which outputs AK Alaska, AL Alabama, AR Arkansas,...

But how do I get this to work?

```
foreach ($states as $key => $value) {
echo $key; echo $value; echo $each-individual-state-count-total from $count_by_state)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the key of your foreach loop to index into the $count_by_state array (and possibly check if the key exists first)

```
$count_by_state = [
    "AK" => 3,
    "AL" => 6,
    "XXX" => 9
];
$states = array('AK' => 'Alaska', 'AL' => 'Alabama');

foreach ($states as $key => $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $count_by_state)) {
        echo $value . "," . $count_by_state[$key] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Alaska,3
Alabama,6
```

Comment: I would do it the other way around, iterate through the `$count_by_state` and match the key to the `$states` array. This way if the full state name is not found, we can simply use the abbreviation :)

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir That is also a solution. You can post that if you want.

Comment: it adds no real value to be a separate answer, therefore I want it to be a comment on this answer

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Thanks, I can see that. My next question was going to be to check if the state count total existed first before echoing, but you cover that.